# When using "destination-in," only the last thing drawn seems to render

Tags: javascript, canvas, browser

I'm making a little library to emulate a curses-like interface in Javascript using a bitmap font. The font is a png with all the characters in it, and with a transparent background.

The method I'm using to render a character is as follows.

1. Draw a square over the space where the character is going to go. The square is the foreground color of the character
2. Change `context.globalCompositeOperation` to `destination-in`
3. Draw the character over the square

This is all done in a function called `putChar`. For some reason, though, only the last `putChar` call seems to render.

In the following JSFiddle, I've removed everything from the library except what's needed to reproduce the issue. `putChar` is called in lines 56, 57, and 58. It should render a yellow "a", a green "b", and a blue "c" all in a row. But only the third `putChar` call is rendered (the blue "c".)

http://jsfiddle.net/r96Lh/3/

This is my first time using composite operations, so I must be missing something. Anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/

> It's important to note that a canvas context can only support one
>   composite operation throughout its life cycle.  if we want to use
>   multiple composite operations, as this tutorial does, we need to apply
>   the operations on a hidden canvas and then copy the results onto a
>   visible canvas.

So, with this approach you may have to use two canvases and blit a portion of one onto the other for each character.

Comment: Ha! I remember that was the first thing I read when I started looking into this method, on that same tutorial. Somehow it completely slipped my mind as I dove deeper! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: The information you provide is wrong. globalCompositeOperation can be changed at any time.

Comment: I seem to remember when I was working with canvas last year, multiple `globalCompositeOperation`s weren't supported in most browsers, but in any case, clearly now they are. @RylandAlmanza should accept the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the composite operation as many times as you want.

Here you can see the definition of the globalComposite Operation in the specification :

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalcompositeoperation

And you have here a quick visual reminder of the various operations :

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html

**So what's happening in your case ?**

When using the composite mode 'destination-in', it is exactly the expected behavior, that *only what's being drawn* will remain on the canvas, and it will be drawn using the color of the pixels that were already there.

So each time you print a char, you erase everything else, that is not an issue, just not what you want.

**How to get the behavior you seek ?**

1) You can build your chars on a separate canvas, then drawImage the canvas on your main canvas.

2) But way easier is to using clipping : By clipping you limit the 'scope' of the effect to only the rectangle where you want your operations to happen :

Before drawing, just add :

```
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x * GenCon.font.width,
                      y * GenCon.font.height,
                      GenCon.font.width,
                      GenCon.font.height);
    context.clip();
```

and don't forget to :

```
    context.restore();
```

working fiddle here :    http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/r96Lh/4/

Comment: Thank you ! Just what I needed :)